# Configuring the AJP port on Jetty in a Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty, ajp

I am trying to configure the AJP port for the Jetty server in my spring boot application. However, I've seen examples about the Tomcat AJP connector but not for Jetty. Can someone tell me how I should configure the AJP port on Jetty?

Comment: what version of spring boot are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot bundles Jetty 9.3 by default. The AJP feature has been droped in jetty 9. If you really need to use AJP, then you will have to add jetty 8 to your classpath, and write a custom JettyServerCustomizer (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/jetty/JettyServerCustomizer.html).

I don't think you will find anything in spring documentation regarding this configuration. Once you get to write your customizer, you'll have to read through Jetty documentation to find out how to achieve your AJP configuration.

Jetty has droped AJP in favor of HTTP connector. Unless you have a real use case, I would avise to migrate to HTTP.

I haven't tried the code, but this should work (needs to be wrapped in spring boot code)

```
 return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                s.addConnector(new Ajp13SocketConnector());

            }   
        };
```

You need jetty-server 8.x  and jetty-ajp 8.x in your classpath. With latest 8.x releases, your pom.xml (if you're a maven user) should contain:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.19.v20160209</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-ajp</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.19.v20160209</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: got any samples i can use?
i tried with jetty9 before and now i am trying with jetty8.
unable to figure out how to configure ajp

Comment: The Jetty project highly recommends using Apache httpd's `mod_proxy` module over `mod_ajp`

Answer (score 0):

Full Sample of The Example Suggested Above For anyone's reference

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyContainer() {
        JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        JettyServerCustomizer customizers = new JettyServerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
//              Connector connector = new Ajp13SocketConnector();
//              connector.setPort(9009); //if you want a custom port
                server.addConnector(new Ajp13SocketConnector());
            }
        };
        factory.addServerCustomizers(customizers);
        return factory;
    }
```

Logs

> o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:7090 o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector
>   : Started Ajp13SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:9009
>   o.e.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector : AJP13 is not a secure protocol.
>   Please protect port 9009 .s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer :
>   Jetty started on port(s) 7090, 9009